# Java Method declaration

Tags: java, methods, integer

I'm trying to declare a method for my program that takes only a 5 digit integer and for each digit of the integer, reads a value from the program and prints it out. I understand this isn't very clear but im having trouble relaying what I mean. I understand it will be some sort of for loop to read each digit of the integer individually until something reaches 5. Something like the charAt() string method but works for digits.

Answer (score 2):

Read up on "modulo". It is a primitive operation, available via the symbol `%` in Java.

For division, it is the remainder. So

```
 System.out.println("Last digit: "+(12345 % 10));
```

will print 5. Figure out yourself how to get the other digits.

As an exercise, figure out how to print *binary digits*.

Answer (score 1):

You can divide and take modulo.

```
while(n > 0) {
  System.out.println("Digit " + (n % 10));
  n /= 10;
}
```

This works fine if you are using any base: all you need to do is substitute 10 for the base (dividing by the base means shifting everything left, and taking the modulo means getting the last digit).

Answer (score 0):

You can very easily convert your integer to a string and use `charAt()`

```
String parseableString = Integer.toString(yourInt);

for (int i = 0; i < parseableString.length(); i++){
    System.out.println(parseableString.charAt(i));
}
```

Comment: What a hack. **Ouch.** Think of a way to get the digit as a number.

Comment: I tried this, sorry i should have stated that up there, but i have another method reading numbers 0-9 so it wont read a character the same, i need it to read a digit. thanks though, and sorry

Comment: @user1701604 then you could parse it back into a int with `Integer.parseInt( parseableString.charAt(i) )`, but as Anony has said it's a hack and needless conversion, but it'll get the job done in a pinch.  Modulo is probably the better way to go in this case though.

Comment: so if i was to read the digits from left to right, i understand the modulo (%10, %100,%1000)to go from right to left, but what if i wanted to go from left to right while only reading one digit at a time, not all the digits from left to right?

Comment: @user1701604 I don't know modulo is messy in that case, I really don't think there is a problem with just converting to string and then converting back for such a trivial case, academically it is bad, but practically it is really easy.